# Can I implement authorization/filter for my endpoints using Spring security based on some information coming from my controller method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a controller method that looks like this

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> getInformation(@PathVariable("id") String id, InternalAuthInfo info) {
  // do something
  return new ResponseEntity(value, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What I want to do is filter/authorise some of the get calls based on info from InternalAuthInfo info object and I don't want to implement the filtering logic inside the controller.

Is there anyway I can implement this using spring security?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an api user with a role then use the @PreAuthorize annotation in your controller

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(ALLOWED_ROLE')")
public ResponseEntity<String> getInformation(@PathVariable("id") String id, InternalAuthInfo info) {
  // do something
  return new ResponseEntity(value, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

Comment: Thank you for your answer @fctmolina.  But how will I pass the information from InternalAuthInfo to my filter classes? This is what I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

This will really depend on how sophisticated you want to get, but let's start simply.

In Spring Security, there are service APIs for retrieving the user and the user's authorities. An example is `UserDetailsService`. Generally speaking, if you are trying to obtain a user from a database, based on, for example, the username, then this is a good fit. This is also the API that Spring Security selects by default for username/password authentication.

So, you can create a delegate `UserDetailsService` like so:

```
public class InternalAuthInfoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    UserDetailsService delegate = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = this.delegate.loadUserByUsername(username);
        InternalAuthInfo info = myWayToLookThisUp(username);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles = myWayToMapInfo(info);
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), roles);
    }
}
```

And then you'd register your custom `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Bean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InternalAuthInfoUserDetailsService();
}
```

The idea with this approach is that you would map details from `InternalAuthInfo` to various authorization roles that you would decide, like `ROLE_USER`. At that point, there are a couple of supported ways to filter:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@GetMapping(...
```

As was called out by another poster is a very simple way.

Or, if you want to maintain your `InternalAuthInfo` instance as part of the user principal, then you can create a bridge object in your custom `UserDetailsService`:

```
public class InternalAuthInfoUserDetailsService 
    implements UserDetailsService {

    UserDetailsService delegate = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = this.delegate.loadUserByUsername(username);
        InternalAuthInfo info = myWayToLookThisUp(username);
        return new MyUser(info, user);
    }

    private static class MyUser extends InternalAuthInfo
        implements UserDetails {

        private final UserDetails delegate;

        public MyUser(InternalAuthInfo info, UserDetails user) {
            super(info);
            this.delegate = user;
        }

        // ... delegate methods
    }
}
```

The rest of the wiring is the same, but the usage is a bit different.

With this setup, you can refer to the `InternalAuthInfo` in your authorization expressions directly:

```
@PreAuthorize("principal?.someAuthInfoProperty == 'some-value'")
@GetMapping(...
```

Where I'm assuming that `InternalAuthInfo` has methods like `getSomeAuthInfoProperty`.

Oftentimes, by the way, the `UserDetailsService` [gets completely customized](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-jdbc-user-service) since `JdbcUserDetailsManager` assumes a certain set of database tables and columns. So, you might instead have an implementation that leverages something like Spring Data JPA:

```
public class InternalAuthInfoUserDetailsService
    implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private InternalAuthInfoRepository repository;

    @Override
    public User loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        InternalAuthInfo info = this.repository.findByUsername(username);
        return new MyInternalAuthInfoUser(info);
    }
}
```

But, here we are starting to make other assumptions about your setup.

The general point here is that you can either

1. Implement a `UserDetailsService` that converts the `InternalAuthInfo` into a set of `GrantedAuthority`s - these will then be part of `Authentication#getAuthorities`

The pro here is that the representation is simplified, only referring to Spring Security citizens in the authentication statement.

2. Implement a `UserDetailsService` that bridges Spring Security's `User` domain object and the `InternalAuthInfo` object - these will then be part of `Authentication#getPrincipal`

The pro here is that the authentication statement contains both Spring Security citizens as well as an instance of `InternalAuthInfo` for more sophisticated inspection.

Lastly, this wasn't exactly your question, but I wanted to point out that users have a choice between method-level authorization and filter-level. They have their pros and cons, but I'd recommend taking a look at [filter-level](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests) since you can use expressions to describe rules for your entire app, instead of method-by-method. I used the method-by-method here just for ease in demonstration.